# Stop browser load from selenium webdriver

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, webdriver

My selenium webdriver goes to a page and waits for that page to finish loading.  If 30 seconds pass it times-out and the script fails.

Is there anyway to have the webdriver stop the page loading after 30 seconds(like pressing the 'x' on the browser)?  This will prevent my driver from timing out.

I'm using Chromedriver.

Comment: My experience says that webdriver really waits for the whole page to finish loading. I am testing a web application which takes quite a while to load, but webdriver just works! Also, I also have included an implicit wait. example: `driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);`

Comment: Also, if you prevent the web page to load completely, it **might** break your test scripts.

Comment: have you looked window.stop() using javascript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the way I came across this issue. I will be using this way until chrome supports `pageload`.

I installed an extension in chrome called Stop load and I set 5 secs stop load.

Then I initiated my driver with the default setting -

```java
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
capabilities.setCapability("chrome.switches", Arrays.asList("--user-data-dir="+System.getProperty("user.home")+"\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data"));
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chromedriver.exe");
driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```

if the page in chrome does not load in 5 secs, your extension will take care of it by killing it in 5 Seconds.

In a way it works like a implicitwait if you set the proper stop load time in the extension

Answer (score 2):

You can stop page loading in ***Ruby*** using **JavaScript** function [**`window.stop()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.stop) and method [**`Selenium::WebDriver::Driver#execute_script`**](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.execute_script):

```
driver.execute_script("window.stop()")
```

Comment: By the time you get access to the interface, you won't need the call anymore. Selenium API is... a blocking race condition mess.

What's more, even page_load timeout will not save you, but rather will simply change the problem. If you access the page that's loading after timeout have given you control back, you will stop the load.

Comment: @Slotos  Did you find any other solution yet? I'm annoyed by this too. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this:

```
   driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout();
```

Documentation: 
[Page Load Timeout](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.Timeouts.html#pageLoadTimeout%28long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29)

Also, as a tip, you cannot access native controls of the browser using Selenium WebDriver. If you want to do that, use tools like [Sikuli](http://groups.csail.mit.edu/uid/sikuli/) if you are using Linux or [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) for windows.