# Keys.ESCAPE in selenium webdriver(python)

Tags: python, google-chrome, firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using selenium `webdriver` (with `python`). I have a use case where I want to test that submit button get disabled once the form get submited. To test it, I send `ESCAPE` key to stop the page to load next page so that I can access the elements of same page.

```
password.send_keys("abcdef", Keys.ENTER, Keys.ESCAPE)
```

The problem is that it works fine in Firefox browser but it is not working in Chrome. In Chrome sending `ESCAPE` seems to be not working and it submits the form and loads the next page.

Is there any other solution or workaround to overcome this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After trying many options, finally the following option seems to be working -

```
password.send_keys("abcdef", Keys.ENTER, Keys.ESCAPE)  # this works for Firefox driver
drive.execute_script("window.stop();")                 # this works for Chrome driver
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try one of these 3 suggestions from https://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/6208 :

- [Installing an extension in Chrome called Stop load](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15840935/175051)
- [using the built in pageLoadTimeout() method in Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15835719/175051)
- [using Sikuli or Autoit to access the browser's native controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15834158/stop-browser-load-from-selenium-webdriver/15835719#15835719)