# Selenium overwrite javascript on page load

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a page with a script javascript statement:

```
<script>window.print;</script>
```

I render that page with

```
driver.get(url_link)
```

I want to replace that statement with this:

```
window.print = (){};
```

So that, the print dialog doesn't come up. And the `window.print` doesn't do anything on page load.

```
driver.execute_script("window.print = (){};")
```

I tried adding the above statement before and after the `driver.get` statement but it is not working.

How can i skip that?

Comment: Not the best way I guess, but try `driver.execute_script('document.getElementsByTagName('script')[n].innerHTML="window.print = (){};";')` where `n` is a number of `<script>` element in list

Answer (score 0):

Logically, it is not possible as you want to restrict js function call made at page load, because the execute script or any other command will get executed after page load.

In order to dismiss on page load, you can perform [sendKeys for "Esc"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34792736/keys-escape-in-selenium-webdriverpython) char after get call .

Comment: Can you suggest me on how to skip the print dialog?